# redirect http to https problems

Tags: 2013, redirect, https

I switched my web app url from http to https. Everything worked fine with https except the links on pages. they pointed to the old url. I deleted the old url on ISS manager site and now I am left with https binding only. Now the links point out to new https url and links at hte top bar (neewfeed, one drive, sites ) even though they are https they give me the following error message when clicked on "404 NOT FOUND". Is there any way to redirect http to https ? I have used http redirect which tells me that there is an error in redirection. Should I create again http binding or there is any other way to get rid of these messages and configure everything correctly.

Comment: Have you updated your AAM bindings in SharePoint? Just changing the bindings in IIS is not enough. Go to Central admin > Application management > Configure alternate access mappings

Comment: yes my default aam is the https one, and I did't use http at all

Comment: What steps did you take to extend your web application?

Comment: I did not use extension at all. Just followed this tutorial : 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fabdulwahab/archive/2013/01/21/configure-ssl-for-sharepoint-2013.aspx

Comment: Did you had any error in any of the steps? I always just add the certificate in IIS bindings to port 443 and use AAM to redirect all http traffic to https, and never had any problem. I would say try with a new web application.

Comment: http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/A-guide-to-https-and-c13e12b7 This is the best guide i know up to date.

Comment: Have you checked your ULS logs?

Comment: i created a new bew application, now I am trying to create the certificate using the selfssl
My input is following 
selfssl.exe /N:CN=name.that.I.used /K:1024 /V:90 /S:1664134975 /P:443
after S: i inputed my id 
I get the following error :"selfssl.exe is not recognized as an iternal or external command, operable program or batch file." What should I do now ?

Comment: when I run selfssl as an admin I get the previous message, when I run it as a normal user I get the message do you want to replace the ssl setting for site :1664134975 ? After I press yes, nothing happens. The message that it was successful doesn't display

Comment: Solved :D 
when I was running selfssl as admin I had to change the path since it was using c:\system 32 and not c:\program files etc where the selfssl.exe was located

Comment: Sorry for not replying, i have been working.. glad that you solved it! Are you following the steps in the guide i provided?

Comment: yes, that was what I used , fortunately I am in the first steps of my sharepoint so creating a new web app wasn't a big deal. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extend a Web application to use an SSL certificate, there are several steps that must be followed and configured in the right order.

What i did when i was going to extend my webapplications to use SSL, i followed this guide, which i think is the best up to date. Remember to use a real certificate for production environments. And of course always test it out in a staging environment before applying to production.

[A guide to https and Secure Sockets Layer in SharePoint 2013](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/A-guide-to-https-and-c13e12b7) by Thomas Balkeståhl